# How to make a nullable data sending in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to make a form component, with the idea by made to create a new category or edit (**make this nullable when i create a category**). When i edit that category works but it's not seem to works when a create. this the form when i called using the edit form i use this:

```
<form class="space-y-5" method="POST" action="{{ route('categories.update', $category) }}">
      @csrf
      @method('PUT')

   <x-forms.category :category="$category" />
</form>
```

this is the component:

```
<div>
    <x-validation-errors class="mb-4" />

    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-6 mt-4">
        <div>
            <label class="text-gray-700" for="name">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
            @if (!$category->name)
                <input id="name" name="name" class="form-input w-full mt-2 rounded-md focus:border-purple-600"
                    type="text">
            @else
                <input id="name" name="name" class="form-input w-full mt-2 rounded-md focus:border-purple-600"
                    type="text" value="{{ $category->name }}">
            @endif
        </div>

        <div>
            <label class="text-gray-700" for="slug">{{ __('Slug') }}</label>
            @if (!$category->slug)
                <input id="slug" name="slug" class="form-input w-full mt-2 rounded-md focus:border-purple-600"
                    type="text">
            @else
                <input id="slug" name="slug" class="form-input w-full mt-2 rounded-md focus:border-purple-600"
                    type="text" value="{{ $category->slug }}">
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex justify-center mt-4">
        <button type="submit"
            class="w-full px-4 py-2 mt-5 bg-gray-800 text-gray-200 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700">
            {{ __('Save') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

i forget to add the create blade.

```
<x-admin-layout>
    <div class="mt-8">
        <div class="my-4 mx-4 flex justify-between w-full content-center justify-items-center justify-self-center">
            <h2 class="text-3xl text-purple-800 font-semibold">{{ __('Create Category') }}</h2>

            <a href="{{ route('categories.index') }}" class="py-1 px-1 mr-5 font-bold rounded-md">
                {{ __('Return to the categories') }}
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4">
            <div class="p-6 bg-white rounded-md shadow-md">
                <h2 class="text-lg text-gray-700 font-semibold capitalize">{{ __('Here you can add a new category') }}
                </h2>
                <form class="space-y-5" method="POST" action="{{ route('categories.store') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <x-forms.category />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-admin-layout>
```

I want to make null when i create

Comment: even i tried to use a isset, but it does not work